# C++ (Atom GCC compiler) "no declaration matches 'int ClassName::FuncName(Paramaters)'" using non-numerical types / ignoring set type for default

Tags: c++

I have been getting this Compiler/Linter Error every time I try to create a function member of a class with a return type other than int, double, and similar types. As far as I can tell, the compiler is setting the default int return type for these functions. But I can't figure out why. I have no excess header or cpp files in the directory, which I have also read can cause the problem.

The error is shows up under the addSample function.

`error: no declaration matches 'int BinaryCounter::addSample(std::cxx11::string)' BinaryCounter::addSample(std::string sample)`

Using these .cpp and .h files. Main is currently empty.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class BinaryCounter
{
public:
  BinaryCounter();
  BinaryCounter(std::string sample);

  ~BinaryCounter();

  std::vector<int> addSample(std::string sample);
  std::vector<int> oneCountColumns;

  int binaryLength;

};
```

```
    #include "BinaryCounter.h"
    
    
    
    BinaryCounter::BinaryCounter()
    {
    
    }
    
    BinaryCounter::~BinaryCounter()
    {
    
    }
    
    BinaryCounter::BinaryCounter(std::string sample)
    {
      binaryLength = sample.length();
    }
    
    
    BinaryCounter::addSample(std::string sample)
    {
      return oneCountColumns;
    }
```

Comment: `BinaryCounter::addSample` is missing the return type in the cpp file.  You should check the compiler warning level and C++ Standard used.  C++ does not / should not guess an omitted return type. See live - https://godbolt.org/z/bndvx4YE7

Comment: `BinaryCounter::addSample(std::string sample)`: seems the return type is missing, the compiler defaults it to int while the declared one returns `std::vector<int>`

Comment: I feel like my brain must have melted. I swore I tried that. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Mark really check your compiler flags - you should have got a more meaningful error.

Comment: The flag was much bigger, but I truncated it to the specific error as opposed to adding the extra line information. On a program this small it seemed anti-helpful to include the repeated information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector<int> addSample(std::string sample);` returns an `std::vector<int>`, so at your `.cpp` source file you have to return the same type like this:

```
std::vector<int> BinaryCounter::addSample(std::string sample)
{
    return oneCountColumns;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was missing the std::vector in the .cpp file. This is what happens when I dust off the cobwebs to join AOC